# Add char * to Arduino LinkedList

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, arduino

I'm using [this](https://github.com/ivanseidel/LinkedList) library for a LinkedList in Arduino.
I want to use two chars as item. Example: "AA", "AB", "GF", etc...
Usually I don't like to use the `String` class that the Arduino framework provides.

The first thought was to use a `char *`:

```
MyLinkedList::LinkedList<char *> _myList;
```

but here how I'm going to load the list:

```
// here the `String` comes from another function - not mine
bool Languages::processHeader(String header)
{
    char buffer[8];
    const char delimiters[] = ",";
    char *token;
    char *ptr;
    char lang[3];

    header.toCharArray(buffer, 8);
    
    // Index
    token = strtok_r(buffer, delimiters, &ptr);
    if (token == NULL) return false;

    while (token)
    {
        token = strtok_r(NULL, delimiters, &ptr);
        if (token == NULL) break;

        strncpy(lang, token, 2);
        _myList.add(lang);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I don't think it would work, since:

1. the address of `lang` is the same in all iteration
2. since it is a local variable it will be overwritten when the function exits

Hence, I can change the code like this:

```
while (token)
{
    token = strtok_r(NULL, delimiters, &ptr);
    if (token == NULL) break;

    char *lang = (char*) malloc(3);
    strncpy(lang, token, 2);
    lang[2] = '\0';
    _myList.add(lang);
}
```

Would this approach lead to any bug in the long term?
I tried the code and it seems to work, but I'm not sure to understand all the implications behind the scenes.

Comment: `MyLinkedList::LinkedList<char *> _myList;` -- If you want to store string, store actual string objects, not character pointers.  -- *Would this approach lead to any bug in the long term?* -- It would, at the very least, create hard-to-maintain code, if not bugs, memory leaks, odd behavior due to pointers being reused without you knowing about it, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie are you talking about `std::string`?

Comment: You'd probably be better off with your own type that has a `char data[2]` in it or something like that and just the operations you need on it. Don't store pointers in the list, store objects. `String`'s problem is dynamic allocations, not much point in replacing it with dynamic allocations of your own.

Comment: @Mark, no not necessarily `std::string`.  Anything really that gets away from having to store `char *`.

Comment: `MyLinkedList::LinkedList<char *> _myList;` --> `MyLinkedList::LinkedList<std::array<char, 2>> _myList;`

Comment: One of the reason of not using Arduino `String` object is that it uses dynamic allocation (i.e. using `malloc()` behind the scene and if not handle carefully, it could cause heap fragmentation for Arduino which only has 2kB RAM. But if you are going to use `malloc()` in your while loop, you must well use just uses the `String`.